# How to link to section with `/` in the name in github markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following section in my markdown code (.md file) in github:

```
## src/app/contextBroker/
```

I want to inclue a link to it from one point in the same .md file. However, it seems that `/` is somehow problematic. I have tried:

```
[src/app/contextBroker/ (Main program)](#src-app-contextBroker-)
```

and

```
[src/app/contextBroker/ (Main program)](#src/app/contextBroker/)
```

and the same in lowercase:

```
[src/app/contextBroker/ (Main program)](#src-app-contextbroker-)
[src/app/contextBroker/ (Main program)](#src/app/contextbroker/)
```

but no one has worked.

Any idea on the right sintax to use in this case, please?

Comment: Inspect the section header and see what its id is. Or click on the link icon next to the header and see what the URL changes to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following @JJJ advice (thanks!) I have realized that it works just removing the slashes in the lowercase variant. In sum:

```
[src/app/contextBroker/ (Main program)](#srcappcontextbroker)
```